# Opposite of "witty"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, antonyms

So today my friend gave a really good line about leftovers. I personally thought it was very witty. I tried to give a witty response, but it ended up being kind of lame and not making much sense, hehe.

I thought to myself, "I tried to be witty... but I ended up being **_**". And then I couldn't fill in the blank. I wanted to say corny, but I wasn't sure if that was correct. So what is the opposite of witty?

Comment: How about "witless"?

Comment: In English literature of the Restoration and eighteenth-century period (e.g., Wycherley's *Country Wife,* Pope's "Essay on Criticism" and "Dunciad," Sheridan's *School for Scandal)* the opposite of *wit* (which was a major cultural value) was quite reliably *dullness;* that of *witty, dull.* Still would work, I should think.

Comment: I tried to be witty but it went over like <insert your favorite simile here>:  lead balloon, screen door on a submarine, kickstand on a Sherman tank, etc.  OR ... but I ended up just sounding *stupid*.

Comment: It's a single-soled jest, solely singular for the singleness.

Comment: You're back! Did you ever find what the missing expression was in your [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120310/idiom-for-magic-object-or-idea-that-fixes-everything) back in July? I'm dying to know!

Comment: If it's for a quip, try *twitty*.

Comment: I think you may have provided your own answer: _lame_ (Of something intended to be entertaining) uninspiring and dull: _"I tried to give a witty response, but it just ended up being lame."_

Comment: In your context, "failing" seems perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The opposite of witty could be *witless* but in the following example

> I tried to be funny but I ended up [witless](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/witless)

It simply doesn't work.
Moreover, *witless* suggests that the person lacks basic intelligence, someone who doesn't have a clue, and is dependent on another. Overall an ambiguous and very negative adjective which I would generally not recommend. On the other hand...

> I tried to be witty but I ended up witless

is actually quite witty IMHO, and works because of the preceding adjective. But as a stand alone, and for the reasons I explained above, I think *witless* is best avoided.

Normally this type of situation—a line that comes off as being *unfunny* (or *unoriginal*)—is said to *fall flat*.

> I tried to be witty but I ended up **falling flat on my face**.
>
> I tried to be witty, but it **fell flat**

A punchline [falls flat](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+flat) when it fails to receive the expected reaction from the listener i.e. laughter.

Depending on the lack of positive response from an audience  you could say a comedian was a complete **fiasco** and his act a disaster.

> Most of her jokes fell flat and her act was a disaster

Of course, the most obvious solution is ***unwitty***. It fits perfectly.

> I tried to be funny but I was unwitty
>   I tried to be witty but I was unwitty

[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unwitty) says: *unwitty* (comparative *more unwitty*, superlative *most unwitty*)
 (*chiefly archaic*) not witty; without wit; silly

Answer (score 8):

I would think either [dull](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dull) or [dry](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dry).

> Dull:  lacking zest or vivacity

---

> Dry: not showing or communicating warmth, enthusiasm, or tender
>   feeling

Comment: You can have dry humo(u)r. If you said someone's reply was dry, I might interpret it as being amusing!

Comment: @Mari-LouA - that is why it is great to use.  You can have dry humor.  But if a person is dry, they are dull and boring with no wit.

Answer (score 4):

Some near-antonyms of *witty* (according to the Merriam-Webster Thesaurus) include:

- uncomic
- unamusing
- witless
- unfunny
- corny

The words *unclever*, *slow-witted*, and (courtesy of @Drew) *dim-witted* are also appropriate for the context.

Comment: And perhaps dim-witted.

Comment: What exactly does corny mean? I've always struggled with this word since none of my friends or family use it. Can it simply describe a response that is un-clever, forced, lame? Is it a catch-all for bad lines (or jokes) that you deliver?

Comment: @ktm5124 It's a rather colloquial word, but OED still has a great definition: "trite, banal, or mawkishly sentimental" (It is used similarly to "cheesy", if you are familiar with that term).

Comment: @Theodore Broda Hm, sounds like "corny" may not be the word I'm after. All of the definitions I read for it have to do with something trite or sentimental. But I'm talking about something that was either forced or a stretch - saying something unnatural where a person might accuse you of trying to hard.

Comment: @ktm5124 The word _corny_ has many nuanced definitions; I've heard it used in that sense as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Banal** or **uninspired** could work in this context.

[Banal](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/banal) - lacking originality, freshness, or novelty

[Uninspired](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uninspired) -  dull or ordinary; unimaginative

eg.

> I tried being witty, but my remark came off as rather *banal*.

or

> John was drunk and trying to be funny, but his attempts were rather *uninspired*.

Comment: Hey, I've made an aggressive edit to your answer, the suggestions in it were good. Answers aren't a good place to make comments about the question though, use comments for that.

Answer (score 1):

*A fool* likely fits with how a person feels in that situation (speaking from personal experience).

Answer (score 0):

*Limp, half-hearted, tepid;* maybe even *outwitted.*

Answer (score 0):

How about: humdrum, dull, lame, or stupid.

> I tried being witty, but my remark came off as rather *lame*.

Back when I were in school the response to "unfunny" jokes were to call them "lame" or "stupid" (as in "a lame punchline")

Also mundane or stale.

Some more ideas here: http://thesaurus.com/browse/boring

Comment: And then I noticed that others, even the original poster, mentioned Lame already.  Lame is the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

The word "dumb" seems to fit well in this scenario.

Comment: Possibly, but then it would be better prefixed with 'sounding' or 'feeling' rather than 'being'. Other similar words that also work better after sounding/feeling instead of being include **foolish** or **daft**.

Answer (score -1):

**Inficete** adj. - dull, unfunny, deadly serious, humorless

**[Po-faced](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/po+faced)** having an overly serious demeanor or attitude; humorless.