# Word for Impossible Solution to All Problems

Tags: synonyms

I'm looking for a word to describe a solution that solves all problems, but such a solution is impractical or impossible.

For example, let this word be X: "Having a billion dollars is the X that would solve all my problems".

What candidates for X are there?

Comment: There will always be trouble in paradise! Don. Or as the book of Proverbs says, "Better is little with the fear of the LORD Than great treasure and turmoil with it" (15:16).

Comment: Answered at [Idiom for magic object (or idea) that fixes everything](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120310/idiom-for-magic-object-or-idea-that-fixes-everything)

Answer (score 6):

**[Panacea](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/panacea)**: an answer or solution for all problems or difficulties.

There is also the connotation that there is no such thing as a *panacea*, because such an all-encompassing solution would be impossible.

Comment: +1 Mike, you squeezed this square peg into round hole quite nicely :>) At some level, the *panacea effect* seems to solve "all kinds of problems", but it doesn't really solve them. It's more like a mental catalyst. Did you realize that panacea was part of the popular and accepted answer of [this questions forerunner](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120310/idiom-for-magic-object-or-idea-that-fixes-everything)?

Comment: @ScotM, I wasn't a part of this community at the time that original question was written - so no, I hadn't realized. I did think I was fitting a square peg into a square hole though!

Comment: Hmmm.  Seven letter word, starts with “P”, has an “ACE” in the middle, and the last letter is a vowel.  @ScotM: Are you sure you aren’t thinking of ***placebo***?

Answer (score 1):

**pipe dream**

> an unattainable or fanciful hope or scheme.
>   - [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=pipe+dream&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)

Comment: “Having a billion dollars is the pipe dream that would solve all my problems”? That doesn’t sound right … I see where you’re going with this, and it’s a fairly similar concept, but I don’t think it works very well here.

Answer (score 1):

In computational complexity, such problems are classified as "NP-completete". 
ie., We don't know if any NP problem can be solved quickly; but if we find a quick solution to one such problem, then every other NP problem can be solved quickly.

PS: This might not be the right answer in this context (language question), but nevertheless is a technically correct answer. :)